# Install gcc from source: bash: gcc -v /usr/bin/gcc: Is a directory

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I just installed gcc-8.1 from source using those steps:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.1.0/gcc-8.1.0.tar.gz
tar xvf gcc-8.1.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-8.1.0
apt build-dep gcc
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-8.1.0/configure --prefix=/usr/bin/gcc-8.1 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
make -j8
make install
```

Everything is correct?

Then I add it to update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8.1 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8.1


There are 3 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gcc-7     60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-5     60        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/gcc-7     60        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gcc-8.1   60        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gcc-8.1 to provide /usr/bin/gcc (gcc) in manual mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/g++ because associated file /usr/bin/g++-8.1 (of link group gcc) doesn't exist
```

My issue is when I type `gcc -v`, it said `bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Is a directory`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I corrected that I meant 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--prefix=/usr/bin/gcc-8.1` means that *everything* that is part of the installation will be placed in the `/usr/bin/gcc-8.1/` directory.<sup>1</sup>

This means that your actual GCC binary is probably located at `/usr/bin/gcc-8.1/bin/gcc` (or some similarly-named executable, maybe it is actually called `gcc-8` or `gcc-8.1`).

When you set the GCC binary to `/usr/bin/gcc-8.1` using `update-alternatives`, you set the symlink that is normally used to resolve which GCC binary you want to a directory - resulting in the error that you are now getting.

To fix this issue, follow these steps:

1. Remove the wrong entry in `update-alternatives`:

   ```
   update-alternatives --remove gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8.1
   ```
2. Add the right entry.<sup>2</sup>

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8.1/bin/gcc 60 \
                       --slave   /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/gcc-8.1/bin/g++
   ```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Well, mostly, anyways. Usual prefixes include `/` (binaries in `/bin/`), `/usr/` (binaries in `/usr/bin/`) and `/usr/local/` (binaries in `/usr/local/bin/`)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I am assuming you want to keep GCC installed at that awkward location. Recompiling and re-installing with `--prefix=/opt/gcc-8.1` or something similar would probably be better, just modify the path as needed</sup>

Comment: So the issue is in `update-alternatives`? how do you recommend doing it?

Comment: The minimal-effort solution to fix this is to provide the proper paths to `update-alternatives` (instead of `/usr/bin/gcc-8.1`, use `/usr/bin/gcc-8.1/bin/gcc`, or whatever the name of the *actual binary* is).

Comment: If you want a cleaner solution, reinstall into a more obvious location (such as `/opt/gcc-8.1`), but the `update-alternatives` step will still need to be fixed

Comment: I added the commands that should fix the entries in `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 0):

This is a double edged sword. I am on windows so don't have the linux jargon. But located my gcc problem in a very wierd way. But maybe this will help someone from hours of digging and trying this and that. But cant say i have not learned a lot in the process. Have also found out that I have been in jail to StackOverflow and cannot post answers to a different question I made in 2023 because of this post a few years ago about a bad answer. Thank you to above for your input and sadly I do not remember what i did back then to get through the gcc make part of the original question. But sadly to say i probably gave up on the project. But hopefully this will get me out of SO jail that i can post to my question again. But i at least have a MAC again so i think the gcc thing won't be a problem if I remember.

[gcc 10.4 release for windows](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2022-06/msg00007.html)

and that at least got me to here

[Read down to the soundforge link](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17336.0)